# type interface {} does not support indexing in golang

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, indexing

I have such map:

```
Map := make(map[string]interface{})
```

This map is supposed to contain mapping from string to array of objects. Arrays can be of different types, like `[]Users` or `[]Hosts`. I populated this array:

```
TopologyMap["Users"] = Users_Array
TopologyMap["Hosts"] = Hosts_Array
```

but when I try to get an elements  from it:

```
Map["Users"][0]
```

it gives an error:
`(type interface {} does not support indexing)`

How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to explicitly convert your interface{} to a slice of the expected type to achieve it. Something like this:

```golang
package main
    
import "fmt"
    
type Host struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    Map := make(map[string]interface{})
    Map["hosts"] = []Host{Host{"test.com"}, Host{"test2.com"}}
    
    hm := Map["hosts"].([]Host)
    fmt.Println(hm[0])
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/yZmniZwFar)

Comment: yes, it's good, but is it possible to do it while populating `Map` to avoid additional assignments like this `hm := Map["hosts"].([]Host)`?

Comment: Have suggested an edit to include the code in the actual question rather than just a link, as links can break.

Answer (score 9):

First thing to be noted is the `interface{}` can hold any data type including `function` and `struct` or `[]struct`. Since the error gives you :

> (type interface {} does not support indexing)

It means that it holds no `slice` or no `array` values. Because you directly call the `index` in this case is `0` to an `interface{}` and you assume that the `Map["Users"]` is an array. But it is not. This is one of very good thing about Go it is statically type which mean all the data type is check at compiled time.

if you want to be avoid the parsing error like this:

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []main.User, not
>   []main.Host

To avoid that error while your parsing it to another type like `Map["user"].([]User)` just in case that another data type pass to the `interface{}` consider the code snippet below :

```
u, ok := myMap["user"].([]User)
if ok {
    log.Printf("value = %+v\n", u)
}
```

Above code is simple and you can use it to check if the interface match to the type you are parsing.

And if you want to be more general passing the value to your `interface{}` at runtime you can check it first using `reflect.TypeOf()` please consider this code :

```
switch reflect.TypeOf(myMap["user"]).String() {
case "[]main.User":
    log.Println("map = ", "slice of user")
    logger.Debug("map = ", myMap["user"].([]User)[0])

case "[]main.Host":
    log.Println("map = ", "slice of host")
    logger.Debug("map = ", myMap["user"].([]Host)[0])

}
```

after you know what's the value of the `interface{}` you can confidently parse it the your specific data type in this case slice of user `[]User`. Not that the `main` there is a package name you can change it to yours.

Comment: There is no reason to reach for reflection here. Use the two-value form of type assertions to avoid the panic: u, ok := myMap["user"].([]User)

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, you're right about that. I edit my answer now

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for unstructured data. You have to parse to index string until you reach the end. Then you can print key value pairs.

```golang
yamlStr := `
input:
  bind: 0.0.0.0:12002
  interface: eth0
reaggregate: {}
versions: {}
output:
  destination: owl-opsw-sw-dev-4.opsw:32001
  interface: eth0
`

var obj map[string]interface{}
if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlStr), &obj); err != nil {
    // Act on error
}

// Set nested object to map[string] 
inputkv := streamObj["input"].(map[string]interface{})
for key, value := range inputkv {
    // Each value is an interface{} type, that is type asserted as a string
    fmt.Println(key, value.(string))
}
```

Result

```
bind 0.0.0.0:12002
interface eth0
```