# How to cast interface{} to a map in GO

Tags: go, go-interface

I am new to Go & I am trying to learn how to cast interface{} to a Map. Here is an example of what I am trying to implement.

Playground link : https://play.golang.org/p/3jhKlGKO46Z

Thanks for the help.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)


func main() {

    Map := make(map[string]interface{})
    test(Map)

    for k,v := range Map {
        fmt.Println("key : %v Value : %v", k, v)
    }

}

func test(v interface{}) error{

    data := make(map[int]interface{})

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        data[i] = i * 5
    }

    for key,val := range data {
        //  fmt.Println("key : %v Value : %v", key, val)
        v[key] = val
    }

    return nil
```

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go, especially https://tour.golang.org/methods/15. And _do_ _not_ use the empty interface.

Comment: the test method is like a replica of a predefined method. so cannot change that

Comment: Go does not have a cast feature like other languages.  The feature that you are looking for is called a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).  Use `m := v.(Map)` to assert that `v` is a`Map`.

Comment: One this I noticed is `fmt.Println("key : %v Value : %v", k, v)` here you need to use `fmt.Printf`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496040/type-interface-does-not-support-indexing-in-golang/47496108 have a look, may helpful

Answer (score 4):

Go supports type assertions for the interfaces. It provides the concrete value present in the interface.

You can achieve this with following code.

```
    m, ok := v.(map[int]interface{})
    if ok {
      // use m
      _ = m
    }
```

If the asserted value is not of given type, `ok` will be `false`

If you avoid second return value, the program will panic for wrong assertions.

I strongly recommend you to go through https://tour.golang.org